# Drop remote branch and reset local repo to match remote using GIT

Tags: git

When I run `git branch -a` I get this:

```
 master
  origin
  remote
  upstream
  web_search
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/ba
  remotes/origin/insur
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mv
  remotes/origin/redesign
  remotes/origin/soap
  remotes/origin/web_search
  remotes/upstream/ba
  remotes/upstream/face
  remotes/upstream/facebook
  remotes/upstream/feature/web
  remotes/upstream/insurance
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/mv
  remotes/upstream/redesign
  remotes/upstream/refactor
  remotes/upstream/soap
```

`remotes/origin` is a forked repository that I want to stop tracking. I want to reset everything so that I'm only seeing the tracked branches of `remote/upstream`. I would even like to get rid of the `remotes/upstream` piece in front of my branches, so I only see `master`, `branch2`, etc.

How can I reset everything to only track the upstream branches, and have them be the "default"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to refer them as `remote/upstream` - you can name that `upstream` anywhere on git and you'll be fine.

Those are called *remotes* in git terminology, and represent repositories your own repo knows. If you want to stop tracking that `origin` remote, you can run `git remote rm origin`. See `git help remote` for more info on remotes.

The distinction between `master` and `upstream/master` is really necessary, because git has to know if you are referring to your own local branch (`master`), or the branch replica you fetched from your remote (`upstream/master`). What you can do anytime you want to work on one of the remotes branches is to `git checkout remote/branch` (as in `git checkout upstream/soap`), and git will create a new local branch called as your remote one (`soap` in this case) and set it to track the remote one. Tracking enables you to just run `git push` and make git know that it has to push your `soap` branch updates to `soap` branch in `upstream` remote repository.